# Does VB6's open statement uses the API?

Tags: winapi, vb6

How `open`works behind the scenes? It calls the WinAPI such as `OpenFile`, `CreateFile`, or `ReadFile`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure of the answer, but you could probably work it out using the [Windows Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: Probably the first two, depending on whether or not the file already exists. Why does that matter, though? VB6 has been outdated for a decade. What specific problem are you trying to solve now?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm trying to hook VB6's `open` statement.

Comment: I'm failing to see a convincing reason why you think you need to hook `open`. Please provide details. There is very likely a better solution.

Comment: Simply trying to know which files are opened by a VB6 program...

Comment: Then use Windows Process Monitor as suggested above.  It will tell you every file I/O and application makes, and so much more.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately the VB runtime calls `CreateFile` to open a file.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely it doesn't use de API. The `open` statement uses the `__vbaFileOpen()` function from `msvbvm60.dll`.

Comment: And what does that use? It certainly imports `CreateFile` from `Kernel32.dll`.

Comment: I don't think so. `CreateFile` is not called when using the open statement.